# How to make VBox fill the size of its parent

Tags: javafx-2

Is this the correct way to make VBox fill its parent:

```
    final Group root = new Group();
    final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 800, Color.BLACK);

    final VBox c = new VBox();
    c.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
    c.setSpacing(10); 
    c.setFillWidth(true);
    c.getChildren().add(...);
    c.getChildren().add(...);
    c.getChildren().add(...);

    c.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
    c.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());

    root.getChildren().add(c);

    stage.setTitle("blah"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
```

Answer (score 25):

You can achieve the same functionality without using bind, using only [BorderPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html) instead of Group

```
final BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
// construct your VBox
root.setCenter(vbox);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are making a common mistake.

It's not necessary to create a Group as the root, just directly use VBox as the root and add it to the scene.

```
final Scene scene = new Scene(c, 1000, 800, Color.BLACK);
```