# How to set vbox size to window size in javafx?

Tags: javafx-2

I am using JavaFX for UI.How to set Vbox layout's size to window size?
I tried the below code,but couldnot view the components added in vbox.

```
    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));  
    vbox.setSpacing(10);
```

Comment: Your question is a bit irritating. Do you want to size the VBox or add nodes to your VBox? Maybe, both? Use a title that is more concrete, please. Posting an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) would also be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make VBox fill the size of its parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311596/how-to-make-vbox-fill-the-size-of-its-parent)

Answer (score 11):

This sets VBOX on 80% of the Stage width:

```java
Stage window = PrimaryStage;
VBox layout = new VBox(10);
//multiply to set size (0.80 is like 80% of the window)
layout.prefWidthProperty().bind(window.widthProperty().multiply(0.80));
```

Answer (score -3):

1. To set your vBox size to the main window's size just add it to the scene
   `primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox, 200, 200));`
2. Add nodes to your VBox to show them inside the box
   `vBox.getChildren().add(label);`

Try this **example**:

```
package javafxapplication1;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ABABAB");

        Label label = new Label("Test");

        vBox.getChildren().add(label); //Add new node to vBox

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox, 200, 200)); //Add vbox to scene
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

You can use:

```
VBox vbox = new VBox();
vbox.setPrefWidth(400);// prefWidth
vbox.setPrefHeight(500);// prefHeight
```

or

```
VBox vbox = new VBox();
vbox.setPrefSize(400, 500);// prefWidth, prefHeight
```

Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html)!

Comment: This doesn't set the VBox to the correct size if the window isn't 400x500.